# Delete all history that contains a certain word

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1

I have a lot of history from a certain website that I would like to delete. It spans back many years (I believe 3). I want to be able to do this:

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Go to History
2. Search url you want to delete
3. To delete ALL of the entries for that search, check mark the first item you want to delete and scroll to the bottom. Now hold
   down the SHIFT key on your keyboard and click the last item shown
   (Like PC).  All items are now checked and you can remove individual
   items as you see fit.
4. Now click remove selected items.

[Source](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/fmJHzSQZRjw/hTkeANKwfloJ)

Comment: There are at least 100 pages of history from this website. That's a good answer for most people (so I +1'd you) but it won't work for me.